# Possible to implement this specific API Platform filter?

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

API Plattform search filter is able to search like following:

```
find where value = 1 or 2 or 3
```

OR

```
find where value = 3
```

The filter I need would look like following:

```
find where value = [1 or 2 or 3] AND [4 or 5] AND [6] AND [7 or 8 or 9]
```

I did some search and was stuck on the getDescription function of the custom filter, it seems you can only set on array and not a array in an array in openapi.

My question is now the following.
Is it possible to make this specific filter with api platform custom filter or would it be easier to solve this with a custom controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**yes** making a specific filter with an API platform ***is*** probably easier. Heres a link that should help you to implement this:
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/